# location of Markdown.pl in Linux

Tags: markdown

Where should I put the Markdown.pl to make shell could recognize it when I use

```
perl Markdown --html4tags filename.md > filename.html
```

in Linux, such as Red Hat enterprise 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it anywhere your PATH can read. Then, you can just call it like that:

```
Markdown.pl --html4tags filename.md > filename.html
```

Comment: the command you give is very useful, and I could omit the "perl" so that PATH could find Markdown.pl

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best place would be `/usr/local/bin`. Make sure this is in your `PATH` of course.

Comment: Thank for your answer, and it's useful to me !